# Python: three levels of nesting with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to achieve a nesting of three levels because I need to group some data.

I have a list of matches, and each of these matches belong to particular rounds. I want to regroup these matches into separate nested lists for each round, except I don't want to store the whole match in these lists, but only the scores.

To clarify, we have this:

```
all_matches = [final_match, semifinal1_match, semifinal2_match]
```

These matches have properties like `round`, `home_score` and `away_score`. What I am trying to do is group them in the following fashion:

```
[
    [[1, 3], [2, 0]],  # semifinal 
    [[1, 0]]           # final round
]
```

I managed to group matches into nested lists by the round they belong to:

```
[list(matches) for round, matches in groupby(all_matches, key=attrgetter('round'))]
```

And this is the result:

```
[[semifinal1_match, semifinal2_match], [final_match]]
```

This is not quite what I am after. I am having trouble trying to figure out how the list comprehension syntax would be to extract only the scores (in a list) for each match into its respective round list, instead of having the whole match in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand each match getting the required attributes from your current result using a nested *list comprehension*:

```
[[[m.home_score, m.away_score] for m in matches]
                               for _, matches in groupby(all_matches, key=attrgetter('round'))]
```

Comment: You don't need the backslash: the open bracket context allows you to continue a statement over multiple lines.

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right. Usually I'm not sure, so I just keep one to be safe :)